# Python show entries from the past 24 hours

Tags: python

I want to make an code that shows **all entries from the past 24 hours** of an file.

**Data is presented like this:**

[23/03/2022,13:01:22,Paris,France]

Code for all entries:

```
def all_data():
 menu_data = Toplevel(root)
 menu_data.title('All data')
 menu_data.geometry('500x300+200+200')

 with open('Data.csv') as file:
  lst = file.readlines()

 text= Text(menu_data, width=100, height=100)
 text.pack()

 for i in lst:
  text.insert(END, str(lst) + '\\n')
```

Is there anyway i could adapt this code to do it and how?

Comment: Of course you can, but you need to make an effort to do this yourself.  You'll use the `datetime` module to translate those two strings to a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you some tips so you can head to the right direction:

Use Python datetime module. There you'll find a datetime and timedelta class.

First, you have to find the datetime for 24h ago:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.today()
at_24h_earlier = now - timedelta(days=1)
```

!!! Warning: notice the timestamp don't have any time zone information, so there is no way to be sure that you're really filtering the last 24h.

Secondly you must parse the date and time for each line in the log to a datetime type and then compare if it is greater than 24h ago:

```py
print(time_log_entry > at_24h_earlier)
```